# Change background color with ng-Style

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can i change the background color with ng-style?

this Div gonna repeat so the one of the color is from DB. For the plnkr i just fixed the colors, but in my example is like this:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-2" ng-repeat="type in types" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
       <div class='container' divCheckbox  ng-style="{'background-color':(isSelected?'{{type.color}}':'#ccc')}>
            <input type='hidden' ng-model="type.show" />
            <div class="label">{{type.name}}</div>
       </div>
</div>
```

And the directive:

```
.directive('divCheckbox', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, el, attr) {
                    scope.isSelected = el.find('input').val() == 'false';
                    el.on('click', function () {
                        scope.isSelected = !scope.isSelected;
                        scope.$apply();
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Heres my plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/onLA8vSbtwQu1OxZrKzT?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do ternary conditions within a tag and you have an error since you didn't quote `background-color`. You have to either quote it, or use camelCase, while the conditions should be set in the controller.

So, the fix is to have a scope variable denoting a color (or the full style object) and use it like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/iYkSa2I1ysZutdkAKkuh?p=preview

---

UPDATE

Here's an example you could use to make your code work with your DB (I'm calling external JSON here, but the principle is the same): http://plnkr.co/edit/Kegs95NNyGGySMDzhQed?p=preview

This way you could fetch the 'selected' color as well. That's pretty much all I can tell you with the info you provided.

Comment: Tks Shomz, just a question, how can access in the directive to the data from DB (the row is listening at the moment) because the color is from the DB "{{type.color}}"

Comment: You're welcome. Hmmm, ideally you could inject a service into the controller, and fetch the data like that (simply assigning the color value to a proper variable you're using in the view). The service would be in charge for fetching the data from the DB.

Comment: Shomz, just change it to ng-style="{'background-color':(isSelected?'{{type.color}}':'#ccc')} like you said, but for some reason isn't working. in console don't give me any errors

Comment: As I said, you can't do ternary operations within the attribute value, it should be done in the controller. Please read my answer.

Comment: You're welcome! :) Sorry I wasn't too clear about the both issues you needed to address.

Comment: Since version 1.1.5, Angular does have support for ternary operator in templates.

Answer (score 1):

Both are different styles. Use:

```
return {backgroundImage:'URL'};
```

or

```
return {backgroundColor:'Color'};
```

Answer (score -1):

youse:

```
return {backgroundImage:'someimg'};
```